# Django Template counter++

Tags: django

I am trying to complete this exact code wrote on PHP and Laravel but using Django:

```
 @php
    $a = 0;
    @endphp
    @foreach($images as $image)
    @if($a % 2 == 0)
    <li class="grid-item">  <!--<li class="grid-item2">-->
        <img class="img img-fluid"src="{{ route('image.file',['filename' => $image->image_path]) }}" />
    </li>
    @php
    $a = $a+1;
    @endphp

    @else
    <li class="grid-item grid-item--width2">  <!--<li class="grid-item2 grid-item--width2">-->
        <img class="img img-fluid"src="{{ route('image.file',['filename' => $image->image_path]) }}" />
    </li>
    @php
    $a = $a+1;
    @endphp
    @endif
    @endforeach
```

It just simple enter using pair numbers into the if condition or not, for any foreach cycle. and this is what I have on Django:

```
 {% for photography in photographies.all%}

          {% if number|divisibleby:2 == True %}


          <li class="grid-item"> <!--<li class="grid-item2">-->
            <img class="img img-fluid" src="{{ photography.image.url }}" />
          </li>


          {{number|add:1}}
          {% else %}

          <li class="grid-item grid-item--width2"> <!--<li class="grid-item2 grid-item--width2">-->
            <img class="img img-fluid" src="{{ photography.image.url }}" />
          </li>

          {{number|add:1}}

          {% endif %}

          {% endfor %}
```

The views.py:

```
def home(request): #añadido
    number = 0
    photographies = Photography.objects #añadido
    return render(request, 'photographies/home.html', {
        'photographies':photographies,
        'number':number
        }) #añadido
```

The biggest problem I have right now is that for some reason the variable number which on any for cycle it reset to cero so always enter into the if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the template by using the add template filter you're not changing the context variable `number`

What you might want to do instead is use the inbuilt counter `{{ forloop.counter0 }}`

```
{% for photography in photographies.all%}

      {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 == True %}


      <li class="grid-item"> <!--<li class="grid-item2">-->
        <img class="img img-fluid" src="{{ photography.image.url }}" />
      </li>

      {% else %}

      <li class="grid-item grid-item--width2"> <!--<li class="grid-item2 grid-item--width2">-->
        <img class="img img-fluid" src="{{ photography.image.url }}" />
      </li>

      {% endif %}

      {% endfor %}
```